# How to use shared_ptr in a member which is not a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm working on a couple of classes and I'm wondering how I can use a normal member in my application class, where the member needs to use shared_from_this()?

Here is some code to clarify what I mean (see comments)

```
class Observable {
public:
    void addObserver(boost::shared_ptr<Observer> observer) {
        // add to a list
    }
};

class Observer {
public:
    virtual void onUpdate() = 0;
};

class MyObservableType : public Observable {
};

class ApplicationModel : public Observer {
private:
    MyObservableType mot;
public:
    void setup() {
    // how do I pass this as a boost::shared_ptr, as ApplicationModel is not 
    // a boost::shared_ptr in the Application class this using a call to 
    // "shared_from_this()" (and inheriting public shared_from_this<ApplicationModel>
        mot.addObserver([shared_from_this]) 
    }
};

class Application {
private:
    ApplicationModel model;
public:
    void setup() {
        model.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three solutions to this problem:

**First solution**: force the application to create a shared_ptr by making its constructor private. This is what I would recommend to do for any class that derivates from `enable_shared_from_this`

```
class ApplicationModel : public Observer, public boost::enable_shared_from_this<ApplicationModel> {
private:
    ApplicationModel(); // private constructor

    MyObservableType mot;
public:
    // an instance of this class can only be created using this function
    static boost::shared_ptr<ApplicationModel> buildApplicationModel() {
        return boost::make_shared<ApplicationModel>();
    }

    void setup() {
        mot.addObserver(shared_from_this()) ;
    }
};
```

**Second solution**: change your code design.
You should not ask the ApplicationModel to register itself to the Observable, but do it yourself. This way the `ApplicationModel` doesn't enforce anything, but if its owner wants to call `addObservable`, it has to create a shared_ptr. This is more or less what is called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

```
class Application {
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<ApplicationModel> model;
    MyObservableType mot;
public:
    void setup() {
        model = boost::make_shared<ApplicationModel>();
        mot.addObserver(model);
    }
};
```

**EDIT: Third solution:** use a dummy shared_ptr, like this:

```
class ApplicationModel : public Observer {
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<ApplicationModel> myself;

    MyObservableType mot;

public:
    void setup() {
        mot.addObserver(myself) ;
    }

    ApplicationModel() {
        myself = boost::shared_ptr<ApplicationModel>(this, [](ApplicationModel*) {});
    }

    ~ApplicationModel() {
        mot.removeObserver(myself);
        assert(myself.unique());
    }
};
```

The idea is to create a shared_ptr to `this` and to tell `shared_ptr` not to call the destructor (here I use an empty lambda function but you can easily create an inline structure). This is a hack and you shouldn't do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  `shared_from_this()` requires that your object be allocated dynamically via a `shared_ptr`.

See [this page of the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html), which states:

> Requires: enable_shared_from_this must be an accessible base class of T. *this must be a subobject of an instance t of type T . There must exist at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns t.

So you would need to alter your code to have any instances of `ApplicationModel` be "owned" by a shared_ptr.  For example:

```
class ApplicationModel : 
    public Observer,
    public boost::enable_shared_from_this<ApplicationModel>
{
    //...
    void setup() {
        mot.addObserver(shared_from_this());
    }
};

class Application {
private:
    // Application object must initialize this somewhere
    boost::shared_ptr<ApplicationModel> model;  
    //...
};
```